# How to add a public directory in FTP under SBS 2011?

Tags: ftp, windows-sbs-2011

I have a server with SBS 2011 installed. I have FPT working with security so that a login is required. I have added a directory under the FTP directory called "public" which I want to make accessible to anyone with no login required. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Enable Anonymous Authentication on the directory in IIS and grant whatever account you're using for anonymous access the relevant NTFS permissions on the folder in the filesystem.

Comment: Can you give me a hint on enabling anonymous authentication on a single directory? I see how to do it for the whole site (I think), but not for a single directory (my "public" directory under my "ftp" folder).